# Quitting screen without a prompt

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to exit my active screen session and kill (not detach) the session.

This is done with `CTRL + a` and then `k`, however screen then then prompts you "Really kill this window [y/n]" and you have to respond with `y` to kill the session.

Is there a way to do this without having to confirm with `y` ?

---

**Note:** Screen is being used to connect to a physical console TTY session so I cannot just type "exit" to kill the session. (ex: `screen /dev/ttyUSB1 9600`)

Comment: just type `exit`

Comment: That doesn't apply to my situation, I'm using screen to access a physical ttyUSB console session. There is no "exit" it's just sitting at a login prompt as-if I'm physically at the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CTRL + A` followed by `:` (to enter command line mode) and then `kill` appears to kill the current screen window without further prompting.

If you add something like this to your `.screenrc` you can do `CTRL + A` followed by `E` and then hit enter.

```
bind e colon kill
```

You may in fact be able to get that to auto-submit, if you change the line like this:

```
bind e colon "kill\015"
```

Where `\015` is the octal representation of CR (carriage return).
You may still get the `Window X (...title...) killed` notification but the screen window will be gone without further keys needing to be pressed.

Comment: Great thorough answer, and it works... appreciated.